# Adding Items to model in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a model like this:

```
public class GlassOrder
    {
        public List<BillFarSighted> FarSightedBill { get; set; } = new List<BillFarSighted>();
        public List<BillNearSighted> NearSightedBill { get; set; } = new List<BillNearSighted>();
        public List<BillLense> LenseBill { get; set; } = new List<BillLense>();
    }
```

and my view that use this model:

```
    @model MyProject.Models.GlassOrder
    
     ...
    ...
    
    <script>
            function CreatePartial(type) {
// I want to add items to @Model.FarSightedBill;
    
    }
    </script>
```

how can I add item to my model in script section

Comment: Your model only exists in code run on server and javascript only runs in browser. You can use a form or ajax to send data to server. Beyond that the scope of this question is far too broad based on guidelines in the [help]

Comment: You can add input with `name` to bind @Model,FarSightedBill in js,If you don't want it to shown,you can use `hidden`.